# django-celery-email task isn't executed

Tags: python, django, django-celery

got a bit stuck solving a problem of asynchronic email sending. I'd like to use celery, and django database as a backend. since for now the only thing I'd like to use this queue managing tool for is email, I've installed django-celery-email as well.

Following the instruction, I've made such updates to my settings file:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

INSTALLED_APPS += ('kombu.transport.django',
                   'djcelery',
                   'djcelery_email')

BROKER_URL = 'django://'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'
```

I'm using default django SMTP with such settings:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'cs*****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I did run migrate for both `djcelery` and `komby` apps. And now, using default django `send_mail` core method, email isn't sent.

If remove `EMAIL_BACKEND` option, email sending works, but horribly slow. IF not for the speed, I wouldn't look for queuing this process in a first place.

I use MySQL database as a database backend, and it's error log file didn't show anything while adding a task, so I assume, that part is fine. It seems to me, I've missed some basic installation or configuration part, that can be easily spot by an experienced celery or `djcelery` user, but newbie like me could've missed.

**UPDATE**
django shell work-around:

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> result = send_mail('test send', 'test_send_body_text', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,    'hornswf@gmail.com')
>>> result[0].status
u'PENDING'
>>> result[0].ready()
False
>>> result[0].failed()
False
>>> result[0].info
>>> result[0].result
```

after 5 minutes of waiting (without celery email sending usually takes about 10-15 seconds), I still get:

```
>>> result[0].status
u'PENDING'
```

and after 15 minutes form last check (20 all in all):

```
>>> result[0].status
u'PENDING'
```

So can anyone help me with this issue? I strongly believe it's something simple.

Sincerely yours, Sergey Aganezov.

Comment: Does email sending work for you without celery with current backend?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if understood you correctly. If I comment ``EMAIL_BACKEND`` line in ``settings`` file, then email sending works just fine, though takes lots of time to precess such a view request...

Comment: I am also encountering this issue, using celery 4.0.0rc3 and django-celery-email 1.1.4. I think I've verified that calling send_mail results in an AMQP message being sent (using the RabbitMQ Web Admin interface), but for an unknown reason the worker does not seem to be receiving it (the AMQP message stays in the queue).  I've verified the tasks are registered properly and sender and worker are both talking to the same broker. Unsure of how to debug further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try opening a shell, try sending an email with djcelery email backend and inspect the `result`.

It should be a standard celery `AsyncResult` that gives you more info on what is happening.

to quote from the docs

`results will be a list of celery AsyncResult objects that you may ignore, or use to check the status of the email delivery task, or even wait for it to complete if want. You have to enable a result backend and set ignore_result to False in CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG if you want to use these. See the Celery docs for more info.`

**EDIT**:

usually the PENDING state is for tasks that are waiting the execution or not known.

`Task is waiting for execution or unknown. Any task id that is not known is implied to be in the pending state`.

double check you have started your workers:

```
./manage.py celeryd -B
```

usually if celery can't send the task to the backend it throws an error, but the task remains pending until a worker acks it.

Comment: I see what you're talking about. I've updated my question with info form django-shell.

Comment: then if you have `CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG = { 'ignore_result': False,}` and double checked.. I have no more clue, sorry.

Comment: got an answer, time was completely wrong on the server side, which was conflicting with one module, that wouldn't allow celery to execute.

Comment: I'm working through this same issue now.  It looks like djcelery is no longer in service for modern django installs.  Celery now supports django directly, in case anyone else stumbles on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as noted in my comment to your question. In my case the task was sending to a different queue than the worker was listening to. By default, the worker listens to the `celery` queue, but can be changed with the '-Q' option. The task will by default also send to the `celery` queue, however I had set the 'queue' option in the `CELERY_EMAIL_TASK_CONFIG` to something else, not realizing this would break things. You can debug which queue your task is sending to by setting the environment variable `KOMBU_LOG_DEBUG=1` and trying to send an email from manage.py shell. I deleted the 'queue' setting and emails started to work. I don't know if you are encountering the same issue but hopefully this will help in your debugging.